# T-SQL ORDER BY several clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently working on a stored procedure in TSQL on SQL Server 2014. I need to write a query to order a list of Projects by different StatusIds.

Table **Project**: 
ProjectId
Label
*ProjectDataId*

Table **ProjectData**:
*ProjectDataId*
StatusId

Table *Project* is linked to *ProjectData* via *ProjectDataId*.

Demo Data Table **Project**:

```
 ProjectId  | Label |  ProjectDataId | 
------------+-------+----------------+
1           | Pro22 |      2         |
2           | Pro54 |      3         |
3           | Pro87 |      4         |
4           | Pro77 |      5         |
5           | Pro28 |      6         |
```

Demo Data Table **ProjectData**:

```
 ProjectDataId  |  StatusId   | 
----------------+-------------+
2               |      1      |
3               |      2      |
4               |      3      |
5               |      4      |
6               |      4      |
```

My current result looks like this:

```
 ProjectId  | Label |  StatusId   | 
------------+-------+-------------+
1           | Pro22 |      1      |
2           | Pro54 |      2      |
3           | Pro87 |      3      |
4           | Pro77 |      4      |
5           | Pro28 |      4      |
```

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StatusId ASC)  AS [RowNumber], * 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
        [P].ProjectId
      , [P].Label
      , [PD].StatusId
      , [P].ProjectDataId
     FROM [MySchema].[Project] [P]
     INNER JOIN [MyProject].[ProjectData] [PD] 
     ON [PD].ProjectDataId = [P].ProjectDataId) dt
```

This query works to order by statusId asc 1, 2, 3, 4 but not to bring it into the right order of statusId 1, 2, **4**, 3.

Actually, the **desired output** should be:

```
 ProjectId  | Label |  StatusId   | 
------------+-------+-------------+
1           | Pro22 |      1      |
2           | Pro54 |      2      |
4           | Pro77 |      4      |
5           | Pro28 |      4      |
3           | Pro87 |      3      |
```

Thus, I need to alter my sort query to achieve this.

My question, do you know how to solve this problem? To order by status more or less dynamically?

Thanks!

Comment: Is 4 the only status that is out of order? or is there a later status that needs to be changed? -- there are a lot of ways you could do this depending on needs and rigidity of the current system.

Comment: What's the rationale behind that sort order?  You haven't told us **why** that order is desired, so we can't tell you how that could be achieved in a query.

Comment: currently, 4 is the only one - but I assume in future there might emerge some others :)

Comment: Can you provide your sample data (not the results of your query, but the data in [MySchema].[Project] and [MySchema].[ProjectData]?

Comment: The query that you posted selects [Row Number], yet that is not included in your "current result" nor your "desired output"

Comment: @TimHorton Thank you for adding the sample data - it was very easy to achieve once I had that.  In the future, you should include it in your original question - it will save a lot of time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to map the order you would want them sorted into.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        ORDER BY CASE StatusId 
            WHEN 1 THEN 1 
            WHEN 2 THEN 2
            WHEN 3 THEN 4
            WHEN 4 THEN 3
            ELSE 5 + StatusId 
        END ASC)  AS [RowNumber]
    , * 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
    [P].ProjectId
  , [P].Label
  , [PD].StatusId
  , [P].ProjectDataId
 FROM [MySchema].[Project] [P]
 INNER JOIN [MyProject].[ProjectData] [PD] 
 ON [PD].ProjectDataId = [P].ProjectDataId) dt
```

Comment: `ASC` is the default behavior of ordering, so doesn't need to be explicitly listed.  Also, why are you adding 5 to the StatusID if it's above 4 or less than or equal to 0?

Comment: @stanshaw, I like to explicitly list my sorting order so others don't need to be familiar with SQL server just to know what order something will sort in. I also have no idea what exactly his criteria for sorting statuses is, so I was simply showing him that he can use the CASE-WHEN statement for the order by logic. In this case, I figured I would just make everything else come after the things I have explicitly listed sort orders for. That logic will change depending on others' needs

Answer (score 1):

Not really understanding the issue but try this on your 'status' field in thre 'select' statement;

```
[NewOrder]=case [PD].StatusId when 3 then 99 else [PD].StatusId end
```

Order by that field now

Comment: We don't know if a StatusID of 99 exists - or if StatusID of 3 should be prioritized above StatusID 5.  With the information given, we only know that he wants to swap 3 and 4 with each other, so this solution (while it would technically work on the sample data) assumes too much and could become problematic in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually very simple.  All you need to do is add a `CASE` statement to the order by, and replace 3 with 4 - and 4 with 3 - and use the StatusID for all other cases.  Very easy.

CODE:

```
DECLARE @Project TABLE (ProjectID int, Label varchar(50), ProjectDataID int)
DECLARE @ProjectData TABLE (ProjectDataID int, StatusID int)

INSERT INTO @Project
VALUES
(1, 'Pro22', 2), 
(2, 'Pro54', 3), 
(3, 'Pro87', 4), 
(4, 'Pro77', 5),
(5, 'Pro28', 6)

INSERT INTO @ProjectData
VALUES
(2, 1),
(3, 2),
(4, 3),
(5, 4),
(6, 4)

SELECT  P.ProjectID, 
        P.Label, 
        PD.StatusID
FROM @Project P
JOIN @ProjectData PD
    ON P.ProjectDataID = PD.ProjectDataID
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN PD.StatusID = 4 THEN 3
         WHEN PD.StatusID = 3 THEN 4
         ELSE PD.StatusID
    END
```

OUTPUT:

```
ProjectID   Label                                              StatusID
----------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------
1           Pro22                                              1
2           Pro54                                              2
4           Pro77                                              4
5           Pro28                                              4
3           Pro87                                              3

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

> Q: Is 4 the only status that is out of order? or is there a later status that needs to be changed?
>
> A: currently, 4 is the only one - but I assume in future there might emerge some others :)

So projects have a sort order. The natural thing would hence be to add a sortkey column to the project table. Then it's simply:

```
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.sortkey) as rn, -- if you want to show a row number
  p.ProjectId,
  p.Label,
  pd.StatusId,
  p.ProjectDataId
FROM MySchema.Project p
JOIN MySchema.ProjectData pd ON pd.ProjectDataId = p.ProjectDataId
ORDER BY p.sortkey;
```

I've removed the DISTINCT Keyword, as there cannot be duplicates in the result when it contains `ProjectDataId`, I surmise.

Comment: If he lacks the ability to modify the table structure, would you use a `CASE` statement similar to my answer - or would you go another route?

Comment: @Stan Shaw: It would be a pity to know that projects have a sort order, but not to be able to store it. Yes, a `CASE` construct would be the workaround then. Either in each such query or in a view.

Comment: I completely agree.  However it wouldn't be the first time that someone was on here tasked with delivering data, while lacking sufficient permissions to actually CORRECT the problem.